# Count total amount of references from multiple foreign tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have 3 tables:

A

B which has a foreign key to A

C same

How can I count the total number of relations that references a row in A?

ex.

---

A

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 |  foo |
|  2 |  bar |
+----+------+
```

---

B

```
+----+----+
| id |  a |
+----+----+
|  1 |  1 |
|  2 |  1 |
|  3 |  2 |
|  4 |  2 |
+----+----+
```

---

C

```
+----+----+
| id |  a |
+----+----+
|  1 |  1 |
|  2 |  1 |
+----+----+
```

I want to get this result:

```
+------+----+
| name |  a |
+------+----+
| foo  |  4 |
| bar  |  2 |
+------+----+
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit 1: taking into account that all children tables may be empty

Edit 2: Accepted answer is **inefficient** and will result in *temporary table* being created by the `union` of the size of `B` + `C`, then *grouping* will be performed on that *temporary table*. An explain plan on that query reveals `Using temporary; Using filesort`, both being bad:

```
+------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+-----------------+------+---------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref             | rows | Extra                           |
+------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+-----------------+------+---------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY     | A          | ALL   | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL            | 5    | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ref   | key0          | key0 | 5       | A.id            | 2    |                                 |
|    2 | DERIVED     | B          | index | NULL          | a    | 4       | NULL            | 15   | Using index                     |
|    3 | UNION       | C          | index | NULL          | a    | 4       | NULL            | 14   | Using index                     |
+------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+-----------------+------+---------------------------------+
```

While if you simply sum up the individual `COUNT`, you would only have the indexes being queried to know the amount of elements:

```
SELECT name,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM B WHERE B.a = A.id) +
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM C WHERE C.a = A.id) AS count
FROM A;
```

This would result in the following explain plan:

```
+------+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-----------------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type        | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref             | rows | Extra       |
+------+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-----------------+------+-------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY            | A     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL            | 5    |             |
|    3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | C     | ref  | a             | a    | 4       | A.id            | 1    | Using index |
|    2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | B     | ref  | a             | a    | 4       | A.id            | 1    | Using index |
+------+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-----------------+------+-------------+
```

Queries and explain plan of accepted answer + this one available in the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6CxLEN5A8mcBRx8kvTU3uy/0).

Comment: I have the feeling that my solution is simpler than the one accepted...

Comment: See comments under accepted solution. yours does not count elements in A which are not in B.

Comment: It does, however, there was another problem with my initial answer, it will report the multiplication of references in B by the number of references in C because of the join. Example: 2 times "foo" in B and 3 times in C will show "6" instead of "5". See edited answer. Also, this solution not only seems easier to understand, it's also more efficient as it uses the underlying indexes of foreign keys.

Answer (score 2):

From your sample data and expected results it seems like you need to left join `A` to the UNION of the other tables:

```
select A.name, count(t.a) count
from A
left join (
  select id, a from B
  union all
  select id, a from C
) t
on A.id = t.a  
group by A.id, A.name
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/igYDGTYkApq1tY6pKDBu1k/1).
Results:

```
| name | count |
| ---- | ----- |
| foo  | 4     |
| bar  | 2     |
```

Comment: it does not handle the case where B is empty. To reproduce it, clear B table and you'll get 0 two times

Comment: Check the edited code if this is your requirement.

Comment: [This](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/igYDGTYkApq1tY6pKDBu1k/0) should outputs foo:3 and bar:2

Comment: This is the case for UNION ALL. Check my edited answer.

Comment: This answer does not benefit from the fact that the underlying indexes available thanks to the foreign key are used to directly access the count per elements. Instead, it creates an intermediate table in which every elements are individually counted.